# debugging crash logs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following crash logs:

[image]

I am unsure my self, why this is happening. Any pointers? I think it has to do with blocks

Comment: Where is this coming from exactly?  And what is the method `-setupTCPConnection`?

Comment: It's hard to know. It's inside the system frameworks, but that doesn't mean it's not your bug. I doubt it has much to do with blocks, particularly; it's just that the framework is using blocks behind the scenes to implement CFNetwork. I suspect a memory management bug (you've over-released or under-retained something) or, perhaps, a memory smashing bug.

Comment: that is the hard question all the debugger gives me is this

Comment: @KenThomases: I don't know, I'd say he's facing a GGD problem myself.  Internally, the majority of those calls are to the Dispatch dylib.

Comment: But they just call blocks evidently queued by CFNetwork. If there were a block of his own, then one of the stack frames would be in his code. They're all in system libraries and frameworks.

Comment: Might you be streaming... Say 6 streams with the BASS for iOS lib?